# Как корренктно записать код в переменную js

Tags: php, javascript

Нужно весь код страницы неизменно сохранить в переменную js, и использовать её. Пробую таким способом:

```
var str = '<?php echo $html;?>';
```

Но выходит куча ошибок то с кавычками то еще с чем то.. Всех не исправить) Как корректно занести в переменную код чтобы он остался неизменным?

Answer (score 1):

Идеологически верный бескостыльный вариант:

```
var str = <?php echo json_encode($html, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?>;
```

[(Список всех возможных опций в официальной документации)](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/json.constants.php)

(о том, что делать так как бы плохо независимо от способа, и о шаблонизаторах пусть расскажет кто-нибудь другой)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $html="<html> 'test' </html>";
?>
 var str = decodeURIComponent('<?php echo urlencode($html); ?>');
```

Если в html есть русский текст, он должен быть в UTF-8, иначе JS не сможет с ним работать.